# Datatable jquery call php when value is reached in row

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have a datatable that runs with date/time cells.  I want to run a php file when my time limits are reached for that particular row.  I have $.ajax setup, but it does not get passed it being called.  Do I have to do something different when it is tied to a <.tr>?

```
    if ( now >= MinTim ) {
      $.ajax({
        url: 'myfile.php',
      })
    }
```

I've added type: 'POST', but that does not work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the statement true?

Comment: Yes, the statement is true.  I discovered yesterday that with my php file, I am missing input elements.  Working through that now.